# It is good, it is bad, it is powerful

Tags: riddle, word

> **1.  Take 0 out then you are really in it**
>
> **2.  Take 1 out then it is unreal**
>
> **3.  Take 2 out, then you are back to 1**
>
> **4.  Take 3 out, then you are now in US**
>
> **5.  Take 4 out, then you are back to 0**

What word am I?

Hint 1

> The numbering of the clues is part of the puzzle.

Hint 2

> Numbers are part of the word

Hint 3

> Starts with a vowel and ends with a vowel

Hint 4

Five letter word with 3 vowels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This layered word may be

> ozone

1. Take 0 out then you are really in it

> (o)**zone**  - in the zone

2. Take 1 out then it is unreal

> **oz**(one)  - the magical Land of Oz

3. Take 2 out, then you are back to 1

> (oz)**one**  - giving one

4. Take 3 out, then you are now in US

> (ozo)**ne** - removing three letters gives Nebraska

5. Take 4 out, then you are back to 0

> **o**(zone)  - removing four letters leaves o for 0

Title: It is good, it is bad, it is powerful

> good - its layer absorbs the Sun's harmful ultraviolet light
>  bad - it is a deadly poisonous gas
>  powerful - it is a very powerful oxidizing agent

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer might be

> Span

1. Take 0 out then you are really in it

> The **span** of something is its full extent, end to end which we could claim to be in.

2. Take 1 out then it is unreal

> Take one letter out and we get **Pan**, which can refer either to the [Greek God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_(god)) or perhaps [Peter Pan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Pan)

3. Take 2 out, then you are back to 1

> Take two letters out and we get **an** - the form of the indefinite article used before words beginning with a vowel sound, indicating one.

4. Take 3 out, then you are back to 1

> Take three letters out and we get **a** - the form of the indefinite article used before words beginning with a consonant sound, also indicating one.

5. Take 4 out, then you are back to 0

> If we take all four letters, there are none left.

Comment: Look at the title. Does your answer fit the title?

Comment: And Gur ahzorevat bs gur pyhrf vf vagragvbany. Part of the puzzle.